# How to check for existence of a key in plist?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to check for the existence of a key in a plist file in xcode.
My plist file has this structure.

```
Root (Dictionary)
+- Parent1 (Dictionary)
   - Key1 (Boolean)
   - Key2 (Boolean)
   - Key3 (Boolean)
   - Key4 (Boolean)

+- Parent2 (Dictionary)
   - Key1 (Boolean)
   - Key2 (Boolean)
```

Now i need to check if Key2 exists in Parent1 or not? I checked NSDictionary but couldnt get how to do this.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"your.plist"];
 BOOL key2Exists = [[dict objectForKey:@"Parent1"] objectForKey:@"Key2"] != nil;
```

As for the explicit `nil` comparison, I sometimes use it because it makes the code more readable for me (it reminds me that the variable on the left side of the statement is a boolean). I’ve also seen an explicit “boolean cast”:

```
BOOL key2Exists = !![[dict objectForKey:@"Parent1"] objectForKey:@"Key2"];
```

I guess it’s a matter of personal preference.

Comment: `BOOL key2Exists = [subDict objectForKey:@"Key2"];` will do; the `!= nil` bit is superfluous.

Comment: @Williham: If !=nil is not used, a warning appears, so i guess its better to use !=nil

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"some.plist"];
NSDictionary *parentDictionary = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Parent1"];

NSSet *allKeys = [NSSet arrayWithSet:[parentDictionary allKeys]];
BOOL keyExists = [allKeys containsObject:@"Key2"];
```